# Running AODV protocol on OMNET++ with Multiple Ethernet Interfaces

Tags: omnet++, ethernet

I'm attempting to run the built-in AODV protocol on OMNET++ using ethernet connections. In my setup, I need each node to have at least two (sometimes three) connection interfaces. However, from what I gather, the protocol seems to support only a single interface (e.g., "eth0").

To address this limitation, I've used ethhub to connect to the eth0 interface, which should broadcast messages to all other connections, allowing them to be received through ports eth1, eth2, etc.

Issue:

When I send a message through the eth0 interface, and a node receives a message (any message), the node queries its IP address and retrieves the IP of the eth1 interface. Thus, to send a message to a particular node, I have to specify the eth1 address of the destination node.

The problem arises when the destination node attempts to send a RREP back. The next hop identified is the eth0 IP address of the previous node (since that's the address from which the message was sent). However, the source node is set up to only receive through the eth1 interface, causing the RREP to never be forwarded.

Is there a way to address this discrepancy or an alternative approach to implement AODV with multiple ethernet interfaces in OMNET++?

Heres the .ned configuration:

```
import inet.common.scenario.ScenarioManager;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.RoutingTableRecorder;
import inet.node.aodv.AodvRouter;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.physicallayer.unitdisk.UnitDiskRadioMedium;
import ned.DatarateChannel;
import inet.routing.aodv.Aodv;
import inet.linklayer.ethernet.EtherHub;

network AODVWiredNetwork
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;
        @display("bgb=1000,1000;bgi=background/streetmap;bgu=m");

    types:
        channel ethline extends DatarateChannel
        {
            delay = 50ns;
            datarate = 100Mbps;
        }

    submodules:

        radioMedium: UnitDiskRadioMedium {
            parameters:
                @display("p=98.1,26.16;is=s");
        }


        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                config = xmldoc("ip_config.xml");


                @display("p=100,100;is=s");


        }
        routingTableRecorder: RoutingTableRecorder {
            parameters:
                @display("p=218.43599,28.776;is=s");
        }

        scenarioManager: ScenarioManager {
            parameters:
                script = default(xml("<scenario/>"));
                @display("p=218.43599,113.796;is=s");
        }

        host[numHosts]: AodvRouter {
            parameters:

                @display("i=device/satellite");
                aodv.activeRouteTimeout = 6s;
                interfaceTable.displayAddresses = true;
                aodv.ttlStart = 20;
                numWlanInterfaces = 0;
                numEthInterfaces = 3;
                aodv.interface = "eth0";

        }
        hostSendHub[numHosts]: EtherHub;

    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..numHosts-2 {
            //withhub
            host[i].ethg[0] <--> ethline <--> hostSendHub[i].ethg++;
            host[i].ethg[1] <--> ethline <--> hostSendHub[i+1].ethg++;
            hostSendHub[i].ethg++ <--> ethline <--> host[i+1].ethg[2];


        }
}
```

Heres the IP configuration:

`<config> <interface hosts='*' address='192.168.x.x' netmask='255.255.255.x'/> </config>`

And heres the .ini file:

```
[General]

description = routing without mobility
num-rngs = 3


*.numHosts = 26 

//# Defining the nodes as stationary and assigning locatinos

*.*host[*].mobility.typename = "StationaryMobility"

*.host[*].mobility.initFromDisplayString = false


[Config Wired]
description = a wired setup using ethernet connection
network = AODVWiredNetwork

**.eth[*].typename="EthernetInterface"

**.eth[*].mac.queue.typename = "EtherQosQueue"
**.eth[*].mac.queue.dataQueue.typename = "DropTailQueue"
**.eth[*].mac.queue.dataQueue.packetCapacity = 10



**.host[*].aodv.interface = "eth0" 
**.eth[*].mac.duplexMode = true
```

I've tried to chand the Aodv.cc file to run on few interfaces unsuccessfully.